# Fill new column based on conditions defined in a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have the conditions to fill a new column defined in a string.

```
condition_string =  "colA='yes' & colB='yes' & (colC='yes' | colD='yes'): 'Yes', colA='no' & colB='no' & (colC='no' | colD='no'): 'No', ELSE : 'UNKNOWN'"
```

The string can be re-written/structured in any other format (dictionary) and then be fed into the code to get the end result.

The dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB03', 'AB04','AB05', 'AB06'],
            'colA': ["yes","yes",'yes',"no","no",'yes', np.nan],
            'colB': [np.nan,'yes','yes',"no",'no', np.nan, "yes"],
            'colC': ["yes",'yes', 'yes',"no", "no",np.nan,np.nan],
            'colD': ["yes",'no', 'yes',"no",np.nan,"no",np.nan],
    }
    )
```

The end result should look like this
[image]

How can I get this done without hardcoding the stuff in the `condition_string`. Or do you have any ways in which the `condition_string` can be restructured and then apply to the dataframe?

UPDATE:
What if the dictionary is like?

```
condition_string =  "colA='yes' & (colB='yes' | colB='no)' & 
(colC='yes' | colD='yes'): 'Yes', colA='no' & colB='no' & (colC='no' |    colD='no'): 'No', ELSE : 'UNKNOWN'"
```

and the dataframe is like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB03', 'AB04','AB05', 'AB06'],
            'colA': ["yes","yes",'yes',"no","no",'yes', np.nan],
            'colB': ["no",'yes','yes',"no",'no', np.nan, "yes"],
            'colC': ["yes",'yes', 'yes',"no", "no",np.nan,np.nan],
            'colD': ["yes",'no', 'yes',"no",np.nan,"no",np.nan]
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution to convert your condition to a python function and then applying it to the rows of your DataFrame:

```
import re

condition_string =  "colA='yes' & colB='yes' & (colC='yes' | colD='yes'): 'Yes', colA='no' & colB='no' & (colC='no' | colD='no'): 'No', ELSE : 'UNKNOWN'"

# formatting string as python function apply_cond
for col in df.columns:
    condition_string = re.sub(rf"(\W|^){col}(\W|$)", rf"\1row['{col}']\2", condition_string)
    condition_string = re.sub(rf"row\['{col}'\]\s*=(?!=)", f"row['{col}']==", condition_string)

cond_form = re.sub(r'(:[^[(]+), (?!ELSE)', r'\1\n\telif ', condition_string) \
            .replace(": ", ":\n\t\treturn ") \
            .replace("&", "and") \
            .replace('|', 'or')
cond_form = re.sub(r", ELSE\s*:", "\n\telse:", cond_form)
function_def = "def apply_cond(row):\n\tif " + cond_form
#print(function_def) # uncomment to see how the function is defined

# executing the function definition of apply_cond
exec(function_def)

# applying the function to each row
df["result"]=df.apply(lambda x: apply_cond(x), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID colA colB colC colD   result
0  AB01  yes  NaN  yes  yes  UNKNOWN
1  AB02  yes  yes  yes   no      Yes
2  AB03  yes  yes  yes  yes      Yes
3  AB03   no   no   no   no       No
4  AB04   no   no   no  NaN       No
5  AB05  yes  NaN  NaN   no  UNKNOWN
6  AB06  NaN  yes  NaN  NaN  UNKNOWN
```

You might want to adapt string formatting depending on `condition_string` (I did it quickly, there might be some unsupported combinations) but if you get those strings automatically it will save you from defining them all over again.

Comment: What if the dictionary is updated to the above format? Can the be made to work for the above updated dataframe scenario?

Comment: if I change `condition_string` to   `condition_string =  "colA='yes' & colB in ['yes','no'] & (colC='yes' | colD='yes'): 'Yes', colA='no' & colB='no' & (colC='no' | colD='no'): 'No', ELSE : 'UNKNOWN'"  
`  The `function_def` doesn't return with `row` attached to `colB`

Comment: In your question you have an error in the second `condition_string`. A parenthesis closes before an encloses quote. It should be: `condition_string =  "colA='yes' & (colB='yes' | colB='no') & (colC='yes' | colD='yes'): 'Yes', colA='no' & colB='no' & (colC='no' |    colD='no'): 'No', ELSE : 'UNKNOWN'"`

Comment: Regarding `colB in` I've updated my code, check it out! Like I said, depending on the syntax of your `condition_string` you might want to extend the substitutions.

Comment: How do I update if the `condition_string` can also like such case `condition_string = "col.A in ['Osel', 'Quine', 'Lovir (Kaletra)', 'Lan ate', 'Dar/cob']: 'Yes', ELSE: col.B"` , I've been trying to extend the substitutions, but no success

Comment: I've updated my answer to replace column names everywhere. I also take into account the fact that else can be followed by a whitespace or not, that column names may include dots... Next time please add enough examples to your question so that we better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['results'] =  np.where((((df['colA']=='yes') & (df['colB']=='yes')) & ((df['colC']=='yes') | (df['colD']=='yes'))), 'Yes',np.where(((df['colA']=='no') & (df['colB']=='no')) & ((df['colC']=='no' )| (df['colD']=='no')), 'No','UNKNOWN'))
```

which gives:

```
 ID colA colB colC colD decision
0  AB01  yes  NaN  yes  yes  UNKNOWN
1  AB02  yes  yes  yes   no      Yes
2  AB03  yes  yes  yes  yes      Yes
3  AB03   no   no   no   no       No
4  AB04   no   no   no  NaN       No
5  AB05  yes  NaN  NaN   no  UNKNOWN
6  AB06  NaN  yes  NaN  NaN  UNKNOWN
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. I don't want to hardcode the stuff in condition_string. I want to get it from condition_string itself or restructure it into a dictionary that can be used to apply to the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to create arbitrary conditions for your `df`, which can be done using `functools.reduce` and `operator.and_`. You can then set up your conditions using two lists (instead of a dict), first one being the columns, second one the string to test against and finally `np.select`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

cols = ["colA", "colB", ["colC", "colD"]] # group the cols in a list if they belong to the same group
answer = ["yes", "no"]

conds = [reduce(and_, [df[i].eq(ans) if isinstance(i, str) else df[i].eq(ans).any(1)
                       for i in cols]) for ans in answer]

df["result"] = np.select(conds, answer, "Unknown")

print (df)

     ID colA colB colC colD   result
0  AB01  yes  NaN  yes  yes  Unknown
1  AB02  yes  yes  yes   no      yes
2  AB03  yes  yes  yes  yes      yes
3  AB03   no   no   no   no       no
4  AB04   no   no   no  NaN       no
5  AB05  yes  NaN  NaN   no  Unknown
6  AB06  NaN  yes  NaN  NaN  Unknown
```

Now you simply need to edit the two lists `cols` and `answer` if you need to adjust your conditions.