# Append an empty output column in the dataset by comparing conditions defined to the input columns using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    Temperature Humidity    Moisture    observation
0   51  29.5    0   
1   51  29.5    188 
2   50  29.5    0   
3   50  29.5    350 
4   50  29.5    0
```

This is the dataset with input columns (temperature, humidity and moisture) and an empty output column (observation).
I need to fill out the observation column with the conditions such as

1. tempearture = 40
2. humidity = 50
3. moisture = 150
   If the values of all the three mentioned above are  less than that as mentioned then the observation column show append an output as "yes".
   if the values of all the three input rows are greater than that as mentioned then the observation row should append an output as "no".
   What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df['observation'] = np.where(((df['Temperature']<=40) & (df['Humidity']<=50) & (df['Moisture']<150)) , 'yes', 'no')
```

which gives:

```
Temperature  Humidity  Moisture observation
0           51      29.5         0          no
1           51      29.5       188          no
2           50      29.5         0          no
3           50      29.5       350          no
4           50      29.5         0          no
```

Note that your conditions are ambiguous. Did you mean all three satisfy these at the same time or if any of them is satisfies.

Comment: what if I want to get an output describing the reason other than simply saying " yes " or " no "  and display an output if any two of the conditions got satisfied and the other one is not satisfied , then i should get an output like " temperature is less "(describing the reason other than simply giving an output as "no")

Comment: Then you nest another np.where within. See example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750850/fill-new-column-based-on-conditions-defined-in-a-string/69751260#69751260